# How could I make my discord bot react to only png, jpg and gifs if it's reacting to every message sent

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot does react with the 2 emojis below when an attachment is send but it also reacts to message when set and and then a link is sent is there anyway i could specify it to only react to the png jpg jpeg and gifs?

```
const attachments = new Discord.MessageAttachment

client.on("message", message => {

  if (message.attachments.size > 0)

      message.react("⬆️")
    
      message.react("⬇️")
       
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, JavaScript requires braces (`{` and `}`) around multiple statements in an `if`, unlike indentation-sensitive languages such as Python. Your current code would react with ⬇️ no matter how many attachments were in the message.

To only react if any of the message attachments were a PNG, JPG, or a GIF, you can use this code:

```
// some takes a predicate function and returns true if any attachment matches the
// predicate
if (message.attachments.some(attachment => {
  // Get the extension from the attachment name
  const parts = attachment.name.split('.')
  const extension = parts[parts.length - 1]
  // Check if the extension is one of these ones
  return ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'].includes(extension)
})) {
  message.react("⬆️")
  message.react("⬇️")
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using Node.js, you can use `path.extname`:

```js
const {extname} = require('path')

if (message.attachments.some(attachment => {
  // extname returns '.png', '.jpg' etc so we need to remove the dot at the start
  const extension = extname(attachment.name).slice(1)
  return ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'].includes(extension)
})) {
  message.react("⬆️")
  message.react("⬇️")
}
```

Comment: after using you're code i am getting this error if (message.attachments.some(attachment => {
^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\discord bot\index.js:28:1)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)?[39m
?[90m    a

Comment: @UboyPlayz You need to put the code in the message handler (`client.on("message", message => { /* the code */ })`) like in your original code. I omitted it because I thought it was obvious.